# Make source in Qmake project dependent on protocol buffers

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

I have a QT project building with make which makes use of Google's Protocol Buffers.  The makefile resulting from the qmake appears to generate protoc commands which will create the desired source (*.pb.h, *.pb.cc), however the code which makes use of the derived source appears to be built prior to the protocol buffers.  How should I induce Qmake to create the headers first?  It seems like a make dependency should do the trick.

This is where I've looked:

[QMake Basic Tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-tutorial.html)

[QMake Advance Usage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html)

Comment: This may be a really basic question.  One of the joys of joining a project after it's established.

Comment: Have a look at this block post. It uses a qmake compiler, the proper way of integrating custom compilers: https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2013/06/09/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-qmake/

Comment: I have almost exactly that code in my project.  I think that part is working.  I believe what I need is to set a dependency from the other code which relies on those headers, but I don't know how to tell qmake to do that.

Comment: That should happen automatically when using a custom compiler. Have you also added the headers directory as include path? See https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtMvvm/blob/master/mkspecs/features/qsettingsgenerator.prf#L49 for a working example of a custom compiler